# Where does Owari no Seraph leave off in the manga?

Tags: seraph-of-the-end

I recently finished watching the two seasons of Owari no Seraph. A new season seems unlikely to happen, so I want to pick up the manga.

Where does the story continue in the manga, after the 12th episode in the anime (second season)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95#%E5%90%84%E8%A9%B1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88), [Wikia](http://owarinoseraph.wikia.com/wiki/Seraph_of_the_End_(Episode)) and many Reddit threads (e.g. [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/OwarinoSeraph/comments/4deslg/where_does_the_manga_connect_with_the_end_of/)), **the anime ends at chapter 41 (volume 11).**

For the sake of completeness: season 1 ends at chapter 25 and season 2 ends at chapter 41.

However, as it has been mentioned on Reddit and explained on Wikia, the anime adaptation has some differences compared to the original work (manga).

Answer (score 0):

Other than the ending of Ch. 41 and the ending of Season 2, The Manga (Ch. 1-41) and Anime (Seasons 1 and 2) are, for all intensive purposes, pretty much identical.

Comment: Hi. Unless your answer added something to the previously accepted answer, this is considered a duplicate. Furthermore, the OP was asking where it ended, not if the anime and manga are identical.